# How to route through a Dynamic IP Wireless Connection

Tags: router

I was so far using a Dlink DSL router to connect to my ISP but it would fail every 5 minutes or so.

So I decided to purchase a 3G Reliance dongle that I have attached to my PC and it works very well. It however provides a Dynamic IP adress every time it dials up.

My problem is how to integrate my DSL router to connect to other computers on my LAN so they all use the PC with the 3G wireless dynamic ip internet connection as a gateway.

Will highly appreciate your help.

Regards, sbeeht